# Pandas keeps original row index with df.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a table and select a few columns, work with them and then merge (left join) with the original table.

The original df is something like this:

```
(pandas index)    source         destination        freq
0                 source_path1   destination_1      day
1                 source_path2   destination_2      hour
2                 source_path3   destination_3      day
```

Then I use df.loc to filter and select some columns:

```
df_copy_hour=df.loc[df['freq']=="hour", ["source","destination"]]
```

this gave me a new df, but with a new index for the row:

```
(pandas index)    source         destination 
0                 source_path2   destination_2
```

Is there any way that df.loc keeps the original index?
I want to use the index to perform a left join with the original table (after doing some stuff with the data).

Thanks

Comment: Seems like with your codes above, .`loc` already maintain the original index `1` instead of reset it to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method and chain `loc[]` accessor to it:

```
df_copy_hour=df.where(df['freq']=="hour").loc[:,["source","destination"]]
```

Now if you print `df_copy_hour` you will get:

```
                 source        destination
(pandas index)      
0               NaN             NaN
1               source_path2    destination_2
2               NaN             NaN
```

Now If you want to remove `NaN` values the use:

```
df_copy_hour=df_copy_hour.dropna()
```

So now if you print `df_copy_hour` you will get:

```
                 source         destination
(pandas index)      
1                source_path2   destination_2
```

**OR**

you can do this in single line by:

```
df_copy_hour=df.where(df['freq']=="hour").loc[:,["source","destination"]].dropna()
```